# Придаточное предложение или вводная конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис

**"Как ни скрывай"** здесь будет выступать в роли придаточного или же эта конструкция больше восходит к вводному предложению?

*У него, как ни скрывай, а большой успех.*

Answer (score 1):

Вы спутали с [**КАК (ЭТО) НИ СТРАННО,** *вводное сочетание*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_335). У Вас придаточное - сравнительное.

---

**[Придаточные сравнительные](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/743-231_pridatochnye_sravnitelnye.html)**

Comment: А не может это быть придаточное уступительное?

Comment: У него большой успех (вопреки чему?), как ни скрывай.

Comment: Вы правы, это придаточное уступительное

Comment: Спасибо, Люсенька! )))